# mark data in xml file on google maps

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps

I want to mark some data on google map.
I use eclipse Java EE and xml file is in the same workspace;(workspace_jsp).

xml file:

```
<csv_data>
<row>
<time>10:01:43</time>
<latitude>37.4805016667</latitude>
<longitude>126.952741667</longitude>
<pdistance>0.000555</pdistance>
<totaldistance>0.000555</totaldistance>
<sectionspray>3343.0</sectionspray>
</row>
<row>
<time>10:01:57</time>
<latitude>37.4807483333</latitude>
<longitude>126.952753333</longitude>
<pdistance>0.027396</pdistance>
<totaldistance>0.027951</totaldistance>
<sectionspray>3320.0</sectionspray>
</row>
```

my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=~~~~"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.466285,126.948366),
                zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("mark_info.xml", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("/csv_data/row");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var time = markers[i].getAttribute("time");
          var ss = markers[i].getAttribute("sectionspray");
          var pd = markers[i].getAttribute("pdistance");
          var td = markers[i].getAttribute("totaldistance");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
          var html = "<b>" + time + "</b> <br/>" + ss + pd + td;
          var icon = customIcons[pd] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {

          if (request.readyState == 4) {
              request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
              callback(request, request.status);
            }
          };

          request.open('GET', url, true);
          request.send(null);
        }

        function doNothing() {}

        //]]>

      </script>

      </head>

      <body onload="load()">
        <div id="map" style="width: 2500px; height: 1500px"></div>
      </body>
</html>
```

map is loaded on browser(IE, CHrome) but marks and infowindow..
what is wrong and how can I fix it?? please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is not formatted as xml attributes. You can't retrieve it using getAttribute.  The data is the content of XML elements.  I use a `nodeValue` function from [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) to retrieve the text from the element.  To get the element, you can use `getElementsByTagName`, which returns an array of elements, if there is only one, that will be [0].

```
  var markers = xml.getElementsByTagName('row');
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var time = nodeValue(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("time")[0]);
    var ss = nodeValue(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("sectionspray")[0]);
    var pd = nodeValue(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("pdistance")[0]);
    var td = nodeValue(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("totaldistance")[0]);
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(nodeValue(markers[i].getElementsByTagName('latitude')[0])),
      parseFloat(nodeValue(markers[i].getElementsByTagName('longitude')[0])));
    var html = "<b>" + time + "</b> <br/>" + ss + pd + td;
    var icon = customIcons[pd] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      icon: icon.icon
    });
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/pm0q9x1e/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
  }
};

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var xml = xmlParse(xmlData);
  var markers = xml.getElementsByTagName('row');
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var time = nodeValue(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("time")[0]);
    var ss = nodeValue(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("sectionspray")[0]);
    var pd = nodeValue(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("pdistance")[0]);
    var td = nodeValue(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("totaldistance")[0]);
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(nodeValue(markers[i].getElementsByTagName('latitude')[0])),
      parseFloat(nodeValue(markers[i].getElementsByTagName('longitude')[0])));
    console.log(point.toUrlValue(6));
    var html = "<b>" + time + "</b> <br/>" + ss + pd + td;
    var icon = customIcons[pd] || {};
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point,
      icon: icon.icon
    });
    bounds.extend(point);
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function xmlParse(str) {
    if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
      var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
      doc.loadXML(str);
      return doc;
    }

    if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
      return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
    }

    return createElement('div', null);
  }
  /**
   * Extract the text value of a DOM node, with leading and trailing whitespace trimmed.
   *
   * @param {Element} node XML node/element.
   * @param {Any} delVal Default value if the node doesn't exist.
   * @return {String|Null}
   */
var nodeValue = function(node, defVal) {
  var retStr = "";
  if (!node) {
    return (typeof defVal === 'undefined' || defVal === null) ? null : defVal;
  }
  if (node.nodeType == 3 || node.nodeType == 4 || node.nodeType == 2) {
    retStr += node.nodeValue;
  } else if (node.nodeType == 1 || node.nodeType == 9 || node.nodeType == 11) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
      retStr += arguments.callee(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
  return retStr;
}
var xmlData = '<csv_data><row><time>10:01:43</time><latitude>37.4805016667</latitude><longitude>126.952741667</longitude><pdistance>0.000555</pdistance><totaldistance>0.000555</totaldistance><sectionspray>3343.0</sectionspray></row><row><time>10:01:57</time><latitude>37.4807483333</latitude><longitude>126.952753333</longitude><pdistance>0.027396</pdistance><totaldistance>0.027951</totaldistance><sectionspray>3320.0</sectionspray></row>';
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. but I have almost 10,000 over data. I can't write them one by one in var xmlData.. .

Comment: That is just a work around for loading the XML for this example, the important part of the answer is the parsing of the XML, you would load it the same way as you did previously with your `downloadUrl` function.

Comment: Do you mean 1) load xmlfile in var xml using downloadUrl like : var xml = downloadUrl('.xml',callback) 2) parse it? I'm sorry, It's my first time and I'm not good at programming itself...@geocodezip

Comment: I mean replace the loop in you code that parses the XML with the loop at the beginning of my question.  Ignore the code snippet if it doesn't help you.